# Yii2 js files error `net::ERR_ABORTED`

Tags: yii2

Suddenly Yii2 js files has error `net::ERR_ABORTED` and Yii2 became very slow.
[image]

I wonder what happened. I am using basic app.

Comment: are the urls correct that are shown ? does the file exists there? try opening the url ina seprate window and try removing eenry thing from the assets and refresh the page

Comment: and what version do you have for `yii2`

Answer (score 0):

Js files are aborted because of .htaccess file. I changed .htaccess file and all is good as before